# Custom Maven Plugin - read maven-metadata.xml?

Tags: java, maven

My custom maven plugin should cancel the build if the pom's version is already available within the distribution maven repo for performance reasons.

Is there any Maven APIs to query for repo metadata? I actually would like to read the latest tag from the maven-metadata.xml which lives on the server. Is there any easy "Maven way" to get this instead of doing your own HTTP GET request for maven-metadata.xml?

My argument: Maven is reading and writing this file for every deploy step. Is this available in a public API?

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is what you need: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-repository-metadata/

Comment: "instead of doing my own GET request for maven-metadata.xml"? I am already within the context of an org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo. Is there no way of doing repo-related stuff inside a Maven plugin?

Comment: So you're looking for https://maven.apache.org/resolver/maven-resolver-impl/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/impl/MetadataResolver.html ?